# Accuracy of model is 0.86 while AUC is 0.50?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I ran a few models in sklearn. Here is the code for the same.

```
# Function for Stochastic Gradient Descent Logistic Regression with Elastic Net
def SGDlogistic(k_fold,train_X,train_Y):
        """Method to implement Multi-class SVM using 
        Stochastic Gradient Descent
        """

        from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
        scores_sgd_lr = []

        for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
            train_X_cv = train_X[train_indices]
            train_Y_cv= train_Y[train_indices]

            test_X_cv = train_X[test_indices]
            test_Y_cv= train_Y[test_indices]

            sgd_lr=SGDClassifier(loss='log',penalty='elasticnet')
            scores_sgd_lr.append(sgd_lr.fit(train_X_cv,train_Y_cv).score(test_X_cv,test_Y_cv))

        print("The mean accuracy of Stochastic Gradient Descent Logistic on CV data is:", np.mean(scores_sgd_lr)) 

        return sgd_lr



def test_performance(test_X,test_Y,classifier,name):
        """This method checks the performance of each algorithm on test data."""

        from sklearn import metrics

        # For SGD
        print ("The accuracy of "+ name + " on test data is:",classifier.score(test_X,test_Y))
        print 'Classification Metrics for'
        print metrics.classification_report(test_Y, classifier.predict(test_X))
        print "Confusion matrix"
        print metrics.confusion_matrix(test_Y, classifier.predict(test_X))




def plot_ROC(test_X,test_Y,classifier):
    """ This functions plots the ROC curve of the classifier"""

    from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
    false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds =roc_curve(test_Y, classifier.predict(test_X))
    roc_auc= auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
    plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
    plt.plot(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, 'b',label='AUC = %0.2f'% roc_auc)
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
```

The first function does logistic regression with Elastic net penalty. 
The second function is testing the perfomance of the algo on the test data. This gives confusion matrix and the accuracy.

While plot_ROC plots the ROC curve on test data.

Here is what I see.

```
('The accuracy of Logistic with Elastic Net on test data is:', 0.90566607467092586)
Classification Metrics for
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.91      1.00      0.95    227948
          1       0.50      0.00      0.00     23743

avg / total       0.87      0.91      0.86    251691

Confusion matrix
[[227944      4]
 [ 23739      4]]
```

[image]

```
(array([ 0.        ,  0.00001755,  1.        ]),
 array([ 0.        ,  0.00016847,  1.        ]),
 array([2, 1, 0]))
```

If you see , the accuracy on test data 90% and even the confusion matrix shows good precision and recall. So it's not just accuracy which might be misleading. But the ROC and AUC it gives is like 0.50?. That's so weird. It is behaving as a random guess as per ROC while the accuracy and Confusion matrix show a different picture.

Help pls

Edit 2:

Ok. SO I added the code for using probabilities instead of actual classification in AUC.

This is what I get now.

[image]

As you see AUC of **0.71**.  I haven't done anything for class imbalance. One question. How do I convert the prediction scores to probabilities for SVM etc. Currently it has predict_proba for only log loss or Huber Loss functions. That means I can't go beyond Logistic regression to get AUC?

Comment: It looks like your model is almost always predicting class 0. Your data is 90% class 0 which gives you 90% accuracy.

Comment: SVM is not a great algorithm if you need probabilities. modified_huber loss might be a better choice. You could try using svm_clf.decision_function() instead of proba. It should work for giving you an ordering you can use for ROC / AUC.

Answer (score 4):

Your results seem to indicate the classifier is prediction 0 in almost all cases.

Below is an example where the data is 90% in class 0 and the classifier always predicts 0. It looks very similar to your results.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
y_true = [0] * 90 + [1] * 10 # 90% Class 0, 10% class 1
y_pred = [0] * 90 + [0] * 10 # All predictions are class 0

print classification_report(y_true, y_pred)

#             precision    recall  f1-score   support
#
#          0       0.90      1.00      0.95        90
#          1       0.00      0.00      0.00        10
#
# avg / total       0.81      0.90      0.85       100

print confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

#[[90  0]
# [10  0]]

print roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred)

# 0.5
```

Also, for measuring AUC you should be predicting probabilities using `predict_proba` instead of predicting labels.

```
probs = classifier.predict_proba(test_X).T[1]
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = \
     roc_curve(test_Y, probs)
```

Comment: Yes. I have class imbalance problem. Positive class is 10% of the total data. Any suggestions now?

Comment: AUC is more reliable with imbalanced data. I.e. your model does not work.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I thought looking at F score which takes into account Precision and Recall both takes into account the imbalance data issue too?. 

Also any suggestion how to factor the imbalance class thing?. I tried using StratifiedKfold instead of normal Kfold for cross validation. Pls check Edit II for the code. The code throws and error saying index out of range.

Comment: @Manish: The most important thing is that you need to use probabilities.

Comment: @Manish No. F1 takes both precision and recall into account; but if you have 99% class A, and always predict class A, you will have a F1 measure of 99% (=precision=recall). Notice how F1 on your second class is 0, but the overall F1 is 0.86?

Comment: So then overall F1 doesn't make sense then. Its the F1 score of positive class we should worry about. Which is zero in my case. Right? 

also AUC it shows as 0.71. But I think that would become irrelevant here right? . Since my model is having zero preccision and recall for predicting positive class. is this understanding correct?. How am I getting AUC then when technically its not getting any true positive and false positive right?

Comment: AUC is a measure of how well you are able to separate classes while letting the threshold vary (hence the reason you need probabilities and not labels).  With AUC only the order matters. F1 is measured using predicted labels at a specific threshold.

Comment: Also, I have not seen the F1 score measured across classes like that, but it would make more sense to look at it in terms of the rarer class.